# ZeroBrane - How to create a template

Tags: lua, zerobrane

Is it possible to create a template in ZeroBrane so that each time I create a new file, the template layout is used? This would be useful in LUA programming for Fibaro components as the same information (headers, file info (version, copyright, etc.)) would be on every file created.

Thanks for all and any help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a simple plugin that adds new content using `onEditorNew` event. For example, try adding the following to the config file (`user.lua`):

```
package {
  onEditorNew = function(self, editor, event) editor:SetText("My template") end
}
```

You can also make it a proper plugin as [described in the documentation](https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-plugin).